# awk variable become unbound after set -euxo pipefail

Tags: shell-script

```
PORT=3306
mysql_status=`netstat -nltp |grep mysqld |awk -v port="$PORT" '{if (match($4,/:.+'"$port"'/)) {print "Yes"} }'`
```

I have a problem about shell environment.I use awk to filter the `mysql` listen status,where I use variable accept shell variable. When there is

```
set -euxo pipefail
```

at the beginning of the script.Error present.

> port: unbound variable

But when I comment the `set -euxo pipefail` the command work well. How can I fix this issue. I really want to use set -euxo pipefail in the script.

Comment: You set an awk variable `port` from `$PORT`, but this is never used. The shell variable `port` does not exist, which is why you get the error.

Comment: I use it in the regex match .match($4,/:.+'"$port"'/)

Comment: No, there you break out of the string that makes up the `awk` program and insert a shell variable `$port`.

Comment: how can I use port?

Comment: Inian's answer is correct and proper in all aspects, showing how to use the `awk ` variable `port`.  Note that `awk` variables are not prefixed by `$` when used (`$port` and `port` in `awk` would be two very different things).

Comment: got it,@inian is right.I am not familar with the awk variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in your `Awk` is incorrect, in a way how you are trying to use the user-defined variable `port`. For regex comparisons, you can directly use the `~` operator instead of `match()` as below. Also `grep` is useless here

```
netstat -nltp | awk -v port="$PORT" '/mysqld/ && $4 ~ port { print "Yes" }'
```

As for the reason for the error you have, the because of incorrect quoted expansion around `port`, the shell interprets it as an undefined variable and because `-u` is defined in `set`, it throws error for the undefined variable situation.

Also the backquoted `` command-substitution is outdated and prone to errors, use the `$(..)` construct

```
mysql_status=$(netstat -nltp | awk -v port="$PORT" '/mysqld/ && $4 ~ port { print "Yes" }')
```